# Simple HTML Dom and Curl

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Hi is curl the best method for using POST with cookie and also navigated to another page for scrapping? I'm using the coding below and I can't get it to work.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $data = array(
     '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
     '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
     '__VIEWSTATE' => '%2FwEPDwUKLTcyODA2ODEwMGRk',
     'Myname' => 'justdev12345',
     'Mypassword' => '12345',
     'idLogin' => 'Login',
     'tmplang2' => '6',
     'fm' => '',
     'jc' => '',
     'LoginRef' => ''
     );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://secure.site.com/mainframe.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "sdc_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "sdc_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$output = new simple_html_dom();   
$output = file_get_html('http://profiles.site.com/profile_900.aspx?AccountID=ShopCartUpdate');
print $output;
```

Comment: I think you should also use curl with the same cookiesfile for getting the second page.  Otherwise it won't use the cookies you have set by logging in for as far as I know.

Comment: What part of your script is not working?

Comment: @MathieuImbert the curl and simple_html_dom part. i don't have a set example to go by for getting this to work.

Comment: @Zombaya how would I use Curl to scrape a page?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine up until the end where you throw away the curl response and load the url with simple-html-dom. If you want to use the curl response it should look like this:

```
$html = str_get_html($output);
$html->find('title');
```

Otherwise you should probably remove all the curl code.

Comment: My problem is I need to login with one URL and then navigate to the second profile url to scrape. how do I do that while maintaining the connection created by curl

Comment: You would need to make both requests with curl. file_get_html will ignore your curl cookie jar.